# Determinant of Jacobian of this transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, determinant

Assume the symmetric and pd. matrix $\Sigma$ partioned with
$$\Sigma =
\begin{bmatrix}
 \boldsymbol\Sigma_{22} & \boldsymbol\Sigma_{12} \\
 \boldsymbol\Sigma_{21} & \boldsymbol\Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ with sizes }\begin{bmatrix} q \times q & q \times (N-q) \\ (N-q) \times q & (N-q) \times (N-q) \end{bmatrix}.$$

I want to transform the parameters $\text{vech}(\Sigma) \rightarrow \theta :=[\text{vec}(B), \text{vech}(\Sigma_{t})],$ defined as 
$$B = \Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21} \\
\Sigma_{t} = \Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}
.$$

Is there a way to compute the determinant of the Jacobian of this transformation?

Background:
It is well-known that for $N$-dimensional $x$ multivariate gaussian distributed with parameters $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, partioned with 
$$x =
\begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{x}_1 \\
 \mathbf{x}_2
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ with sizes }\begin{bmatrix} q \times 1 \\ (N-q) \times 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and $μ$ and $Σ$ with

$$\mu=\begin{bmatrix}
 \mu_1 \\
 \mu_2
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ with sizes }\begin{bmatrix} q \times 1 \\ (N-q) \times 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

the conditional distribution of $x_1$ conditional on $x_2 = a$ is multivariate normal with parameters
$$\bar{\mu}=
\boldsymbol\mu_1 + \boldsymbol\Sigma_{12} \boldsymbol\Sigma_{22}^{-1}
\left(
 \mathbf{a} - \boldsymbol\mu_2
\right)
$$
and covariance matrix
$$
\overline{\Sigma}
=
\boldsymbol\Sigma_{11} - \boldsymbol\Sigma_{12} \boldsymbol\Sigma_{22}^{-1} \boldsymbol\Sigma_{21}.
$$
I want to assign priors on $\Sigma$ and perform Bayesian analysis on $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ working with the transformed parameters. In order to see how the transformation affects my priors I need the Jacobian.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\Sigma_{t} = \Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{21}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{12}$ ? (with the middle term inverted) ?

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie for hinting at this point, I edited the typo.